# Firefox for Web Developer?

Tags: firefox, installation, version

Is there any FireFox plugin which acts the same as IE8 developer tools in a way that it has an option to switch from different modes or versions?

I had many issues when installing different versions of FireFox in just one machine. I now have 3.0, 3.6, 4.0.1 and 5.0.1 of FF but I got a problem regarding add-ons, it seems like they share just one location where add-ons are in.

If I open FF 3.0, since some add-ons are latest version for 4.0.1 and are not compatible with FF 3.0, it will disable them, then when I go back to the later version, add-ons which was disabled by the older FF will be gone.

Anyway my platform is Windows 7 32-bit.

Comment: See related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111920/multiple-firefox-versions-on-same-pc

Comment: @Mrchief, It's not working for me, I got `The path specified in the target is not valid` when I set target: `C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox 3.0\firefox.exe -p FF3_0`. But when I remove `-p ff3_0` it's fine working.

Comment: The `-p FF3_0` needs to go outside of the quotes in the _target_ box. The quotes only exist because of the space in the directory `Program Files`.

Comment: @andy, is it like typing in a command prompt? if there is a space in my profile name should I type `"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox 3.0\firefox.exe" -p "FireFox 3.0"`

Comment: @domanokz Yes, it is like the command prompt. My profile name doesn't have spaces in so for me it's just `-p FF3_0`. You might need to quote your profile name as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start firefox with following option

- firefox.exe -ProfileManager

For each profile you can add individual addon's which do not conflict with other profile addons. Ensure you give different names for different profiles in different firefox versions.

Comment: Or probably simpler: create an empty directory for each profile somewhere and start Firefox with the correct profile directory as command line option: `firefox.exe -no-remote -profile c:\...\profile1`

Comment: @Ratna, I've successfully created different profiles, I've set each shortcut on the desktop to different profiles. Now, the problem is, I if one FF is open and I want to open another FF with different version, the first FF's version will be opened. How to deal with that?

Comment: @domanokz: See my comment, the `-no-remote` command line option takes care of that (not sure whether Firefox 3.0 supports it however, why did you install this ancient version instead of Firefox 3.6 anyway?).

Comment: @Wla Ha ha! You know, our clients here are still using FF 3.0, they are grannies so we can do nothing but to optimize the website for them. Thanks!